# Silent truncation of last character when using SSIS with Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am using SSIS to export data from an Oracle database. Sometimes when I export a VARCHAR2 column to NVARCHAR the last character gets truncated (silently). It's completely random as far as I can tell. I have tried using different SSIS data types (DT_STR, DT_WSTR and DT_NTEXT) but the problem persists. The source string is always 12 characters long ([0-9A-Z] only), but when I check the destination database some columns are missing the last character.

I use the latest 32bit Oracle Instant Client (11.2) with ODBC and SQL Server 2008 R2. I use ADO .NET for both source and destination. The source character set is AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1 and the source and destination columns are declared as VARCHAR2 (12 BYTES) and NVARCHAR(12) respectively.

Comment: Try: `select length(to_nchar(source_column)), count(*) from source_table group by length(to_nchar(source_column));` and see if you'll get any truncation due to VARCHAR->NVARCHAR issues

Comment: I ran the query and all columns are 12 characters. No truncation.

Comment: I just want to clarify that the truncation happens in a random pattern. Different rows gets truncated on every export and sometimes there is no truncation at all.

Comment: Just want to mention I typoed the above query. `length()` should have been `lengthb()` (for length in bytes, rather than length in characters).

Comment: With lengthb() i get exactly double the length for all rows (24 bytes).

Comment: I'm very glad I found this post as I had the exact same issue, and was able to resolve it the same way. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and set up an SSIS package to import from an Oracle 11g database. One of my tables had two varchar2 fields with the exact same data for almost all rows, making the problem easy to spot. I noticed that over 50% of the time, at least one record would show a difference between the two fields because the last character was missing from one of those columns. Seems the field and the record that had the data loss was random. In my SSIS package, some sequence containers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem was caused by a data flow task where I had two different data flows running in parallel. The same source tables were involved in both data sources but with different destinations. When I broke the task up into two tasks running one after the other, the truncation problem seems to have gone away.